# In Windows Terminal, detect URLs without an http://

Tags: url, windows-terminal

Windows Terminal's Settings > Interaction has a checkbox "Automatically detect URLs and make them clickable."  That detects only phrases that start with `http://` or `https://`, e.g., `https://www.microsoft.com`.
Can it be made to also detect, e.g., `www.microsoft.com`?  Is there a regex buried somewhere that can be modified?

Comment: Windows Terminal is open source, the only way I know how to acomplish what you want, would be to rebuild the application with the required modifications to the code.

Comment: Holy moly, building from source is serious yak-shaving, even before I learn what code to change.  There's already a [long discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/7562) about which schemes to support -- "schemeless" might be in there too, I couldn't tell.  Simplest might be to raise a github issue that eventually percolates into that.

Comment: So the definition of a URI/URL requires a "scheme", so whatever that string is, it isn't a url unless it starts with a protocol specifier like http://, ftp://, file://, smb://, etc (and follows a bunch of other rules). the scheme must not be "empty": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax

Comment: Yes, technically, a URI must start with an xxx://, but in everyday use (ads, typing into a browser's address bar) it's omitted.  [Gnome Terminal](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal) autodetects strings that start with www, for example; then the browser reliably figures out what the xxx:// should be.

Comment: so "www" adds an interesting wrinkle to this, because its the only real convention that expresses both "this is a location identifier" and also implies a specific pair of related protocols that are both used by the same application, so there is 0 ambiguity what program should be launched or how to tell the application to use it. "mail.somewhere.com" doesn;t provide information as to what application to launch, as it might be for mailto:// or http(s):// or smtp:// or imap:// , each of which may use a different application on your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, this currently isn't possible in the Windows Terminal (circa v1.18/1.19/1.20).

I've been tracking adding support for changing the regex in a couple different places:

- https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/8321
- https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/8849
- https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5916

Somewhere at the nexus of those three threads is "I want to manually set the regex used to detect URLs and make them clickable".

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't.  Not without learning how to build it from source and where in the source code to make the change.  Or waiting for the feature to be added.